# Changepoints vs Structural Breaks

Tags: time-series, change-point

I am looking at this [source](https://%20https://kevin-kotze.gitlab.io/tsm/ts-2-note/):

It defines changepoint and changepoint detection the following way:

> 1 Change point detection
> A particular change point test seeks to
> identify the specific period of time that relates to a change in the
> probability distribution of a stochastic process or time series. In
> general, the problem concerns both detecting whether or not a change
> has occurred, or whether several changes might have occurred, and
> identifying the times of any such changes.
>
> To establish a relatively general framework for the detection of a
> change point, we can assume that we have an ordered sequence of data,
> $y_t=\{y_1, \ldots, y_T\}$. A change point is then said to
> arise within this dataset when there exists a time, $\tau \in\{1, \ldots, T-1\}$, such that the statistical properties of $\{y_1, \ldots, y_\tau\}$ and $\{y_{\tau+1}, \ldots, y_T\}$
> are different in some way. Extending this idea for a single change
> point to multiple changes, we can allow for $m$ change points, that
> are associated with positions, $\tau_{1: m}=\{\tau_1, \ldots, \tau_m\}$. Each change point position is then ordered so that
> $\tau_i<\tau_j$ if, and only if, $i<j$. Consequently the $m$ change
> points will split the data into $m+1$ segments, where the $i$ th
> segment may be summarised by a set of parameters. The parameters
> associated with the $i$ th segment will be denoted $\{\theta_i, \phi_i\}$, where $\phi_i$ is a possible set of nuisance
> parameters and $\theta_i$ is the set of parameters that may describe
> the change. In this case, we typically want to test how many segments
> are needed to provide the best representation of the data generating
> process.

They discuss tests for finding changes in mean and/or variance.

Later on then define the difference between the definition of structural break and changepoint here:

> The term structural break is in many respects synonymous with change
> point, but would refer to specific cases where there is a change in
> the regression coefficients.

But if a changepoint is " a change in the
probability distribution of a stochastic process or time series.", and a structural break related to " a change in the regression coefficients", I do not understand how a structural break is a case of a changepoint and not completely synonymous. How we can have a changepoint that doesn't change regression coefficients?

Comment: Hint: do regression coefficients always completely determine the conditional distribution?

Comment: No,because there is the error term in the regression equation, and that error term's variance is the variance of the conditional distribution.

Comment: (assuming its an AR process) then we could say its a change in the conditional mean $E(X_t \mid X_{t-1}, X_{t-2}, \ldots, X_{t-p}$)?